# what is the authoritative config path for a git submodule

Tags: git

I have a pretty straightforward setup on github, with a submodule repository (also on github). I'm having some problems with permissions on the submodule while the parent repository works fine. On my way to resolving my problems, I've noticed there're two places where submodules are defined.

Which is the primary one? Is it the [submodule xxxx] block in .git/config? or is it the .gitmodules file?

What if there is inconsistency between the two?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`git config` man page](http://schacon.github.com/git/git-config.html) states that the values in `.git/config` are initially populated by the `git submodule init` command.

If the values in the two locations do not match, then `.git/config` overrides `.gitmodules`.